# How can I add days to Ecto.DateTime?

Tags: date, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a date-time which I create like this:

```
Ecto.DateTime.from_erl({{2015, 3, 10}, {0, 0, 0}})
```

It's a Phoenix app. I want to add days to it with no any additional third-party library. How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use erlang's [`:calendar`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html) module to manipulate dates without additional dependencies.

A standard way of adding days would be to use `:calendar.date_to_gregorian_days/1` do the addition and convert back to the tuple format with `:calendar.gregorian_days_to_date/1`.

Comment: isn't that an additional dependency? actually, I have DateTime.

Comment: No, it comes in the erlang standard library.

Answer (score 8):

As of at least Elixir 1.5.0, you can use `DateTime.add/2` to add days to a date.

```
# add five days to the current day
DateTime.utc_now |> DateTime.add(5*24*60*60, :second)
```

Comment: Nice but caution: The result would be a Date, *not* a Datetime

Comment: @ouven Thank you for that catch. I've now updated the example to keep it as a DateTime

Comment: this only works for UTC DateTimes. it will break if you're working in a timezone that has DST

Answer (score 1):

Proper elixir syntax

```
weekday=  :calendar.gregorian_days_to_date(:calendar.date_to_gregorian_days({2011, 7, 14}) - 90)

IO.inspect weekday

{2011, 4, 15}
```

Answer (score 1):

for datetime 
let say no_of_days is the number of days u want to add.

```
{{a,b,c},{hh,mm,ss}} = :calendar.universal_time()
{x,y,z} = :calendar.gregorian_days_to_date(:calendar.date_to_gregorian_days({a,b,c}) +no_of_days)
time = Ecto.DateTime.from_erl({{x,y,z},{hh,mm,ss}})
```