# How to get tomorrows datetime with Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I can get the current datetime with Ecto like this:

```
Ecto.DateTime.utc
```

But how do I get tomorrows date like

```
Ecto.DateTime.utc + timedelta 1 day
```

?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197714/how-can-i-add-days-to-ecto-datetime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How's about an answer for this?

```
Ecto.DateTime.utc 
|> Ecto.DateTime.to_erl 
|> :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds 
|> Kernel.+(86400) 
|> :calendar.gregorian_seconds_to_datetime 
|> Ecto.DateTime.from_erl
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Timex.shift(Timex.now, days: 1)
```

https://github.com/bitwalker/timex

Answer (score 0):

```
iex(3)> t = DateTime.utc_now()
#DateTime<2018-07-17 08:22:11.472192Z>
iex(4)> n = %{t | day: t.day + 1}
#DateTime<2018-07-18 08:22:11.472192Z>
iex(5)> n
#DateTime<2018-07-18 08:22:11.472192Z>
iex(6)> m = %{t | day: t.day - 1}
#DateTime<2018-07-16 08:22:11.472192Z>
iex(7)> m
#DateTime<2018-07-16 08:22:11.472192Z>
```